# I added a project as reference but it still cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependencies

I'm using VS10 and C# and I've encountered a weird problem.  I have 2 project A and B, A is a class library, and B is a console project.  B depends on A, so I added the project reference of A to B.

But when I use types created in project A in project B, VS complains the following:

> The type or namespace name  could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've never encountered this problem before, does anyone know what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: are the classes you're trying to use marked as `public`? (note that the default accessibility level for classes is `internal`.)

Comment: Sure you're `using` the right namespaces? Are there any name collisions? Are the classes you're using really public?

Comment: Do they target the same framework version? EDIT: no I think that is a different error...

Comment: Also did you spesify that you are using this dll inside the class? i.e. `using myproject.dll` . In my experience with class libraries you have to specify that you are using the namespace of the class library in any class before you are able to use it.

Comment: Is your project "B" type is "Client profile"?

Comment: Yes, project B type is "Client profile". They are marked as public.  They are in the same solution and I'm making the right "using"

Comment: yes, vs complains on the "using A;"

Comment: Do you mean you are referencing library on 4.0 into the console which is targetting client profile ? Then [it won't work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have Project B targetting `Client Profile` while the library is built for `4.0` this cannot be done.

You will have to upgrade the console app to target `4.0`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx)

> If you are targeting the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, you cannot
>   reference an assembly that is not in the .NET Framework 4 Client
>   Profile. Instead you must target the .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

There might be one of these reasion.

1. your using namespace statement is not point the locaiton which is
   using the class in B project.
2. your you classA in project a is not
   accessible from the project b so make them public.
3. you are pointing   diffrent profile of dotnet framework.
4. your dll of project a is not   readable by project b. cross check the refrance.